# how to deploy next js app without vercel to custom server using ftp server like filezilla

Tags: reactjs, deployment, next.js, vercel

can I deploy next js app to custom server without vercel
in react js i used to use build folder to deploy using FTP server
in next js i don't know which files to upload
any help please?

Comment: Run [`next build && next export`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export), and upload the `dist` folder.

Comment: dist folder won't be created via "next build && next export"

Answer (score 1):

1. `yarn add ftp-deploy`
2. create file deploy.js outside src
3. Put this code on that:

   ```
   var FtpDeploy = require('ftp-deploy');
   var ftpDeploy = new FtpDeploy();
   require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.local' });

   var config = {
     user: process.env.FTP_USER,
     // Password optional, prompted if none given
     password: process.env.FTP_PASS,
     host: process.env.FTP_HOST,
     port: process.env.FTP_PORT || 21,
     localRoot: __dirname + '/build',
     remoteRoot: process.env.FTP_REMOTE_ROOT,
     // this would upload everything
     include: ['*'],
     // e.g. exclude sourcemaps, and ALL files in node_modules (including dot files)
     exclude: [],
     // delete ALL existing files at destination before uploading, if true
     deleteRemote: process.env.FTP_DELETE,
     // Passive mode is forced (EPSV command is not sent)
     forcePasv: true,
   };

   ftpDeploy
     .deploy(config)
     .then((res) => console.log('finished ;)'))
     .catch((err) => console.log(err));

   ftpDeploy.on('uploading', (d) => {
     console.log(
       `${d.transferredFileCount} / ${d.totalFilesCount} => ${d.filename}`
     );
   });

   ftpDeploy.on('upload-error', function (data) {
     console.log('upload-error =>', data.err); // data will also include filename, relativePath, and other goodies
   });
   ```

   Then please type your database information on env file with the variable names in this file

Answer (score 0):

In next.config.js copy this. This is TS version.

In package.json `"build": "next build"`,

```
    /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
    const nextConfig = {
        output: 'export',
    }; 
    module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).